# How to publish Flutter app on Microsoft Store?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, uwp, desktop

I have built the app for windows. It runs in desktop mode.

I opened Microsoft developer account.

How do I publish the flutter app (the windows build) into the Microsoft Store? What is/are the file(s) (or how to build it), from the AndroidStudioProjects, to upload in the Microsoft Partner Center?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you cannot upload a .exe filt to the Windows Store you need for example a .xsix file. To build a .xsix file it is very easy:

You build your app with Flutter for Windows and after this step you can use the **xsix** package to build a xsix file for the Windows Store. You find the documentation for the package here: https://pub.dev/documentation/msix/latest/

Add this package to the dev_dependencies:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  msix: ^2.1.1
```

And then use these comments:

```
flutter clean
flutter build windows
flutter pub run msix:create --store
```

After this steps you get the msix file for uploading to the Windows Store.